# Slow Json conversion due to JsonConvert.DefaultSetting

Tags: performance, json.net, deserialization

We recently encountered quite a serious issue that we were fortunate enough to be able to resolve, I wanted to share the solution.

We found that our lightweight library that parses and repackages results was burning 100% processor on two cores. Our JSON documents are composed of hundreds of elements. It emerged that the `JsonConvert.DefaultSetting` was being initialised six times per element, where an element is pretty trivial:

```
[
"revo-CH0012221716",
20.29,
8774.0,
1.5372955117461105,
[
"#270028_1"
],
"CHF",
1.0
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed by reusing the same object instance for `JsonConvert.DefaultSetting` rather than recreating it each time (via a delegate) as is recommended in the official code example.

The result of the fix is that portfolio computation time was cut from three seconds to less than a second, and processor burn was cut from 100% to 15% (much healthier).

For "average Joe" developers such as myself I would hope that this 'gotcha' could be at least commented / documented in the official sample code. The document that we based our code on is here:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data.

Comment: Agreed. We ran into the same issue and resolved it in the manner you've explained. Thanks.